# Retrieve all Attributes from OpenTelemetry Agent

Tags: java, open-telemetry

I'm looking at adding another resource to the opentelemetry agent and want to get all the attributes that are used. Is there a way to get all attributes that are used in the OpenTelemetry agent rather than using HostResource, OsResource, etc. in code?

Tried GlobalOpenTelemetry.get() and can see the attributes but having trouble getting the list with my code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you tried combing through the opentelemetry Java API documentation? https://javadoc.io/doc/io.opentelemetry